# Reuse Datepicker for different field values

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make my datepicker reusable, as I need three datepickers, that change different values that are stored in the same class, lets call it `_object.date1 , date 2, date 3`

To reuse my datepicker I tried the following and passed the variable to the datepicker that shall be changed. But then the field value isn't changed or stored and nothing happens, also no error. If I don't pass the value to _showAndroidDatePicker() and use the line in setState that I commented out below, it works properly. The Datepicker ist linked to the onTap of a TextFormField in a Form.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm missing here? It would be really great to make this reusable.

Many thanks!

```
void _showAndroidDatePicker(value) {
showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        primaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        accentColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        colorScheme:
            ColorScheme.light(primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  },
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  locale: Locale('de'),
  firstDate: DateTime(1900),
  helpText: 'Bitte wähle ein Datum aus',
  lastDate: DateTime.now(),
).then<DateTime>(
  (DateTime newDate) {
    if (newDate != null) {
      setState(() {
        value = newDate.toIso8601String();
//Below code works if value isn't passed to datepicker, but I want it variable to avoid boilerplate
// _object.date1 =newDate.toIso8601String();
          });
        }
        return;
      },
    );
  }
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it the controller and the focus node for the text field. Something like this:

```
datePickerListener(node, controller) {
  if (node.hasFocus) {
    node.unfocus();
    showDatePicker(your setup).then((date){
      var formatter = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
      var formatted = formatter.format(date).toString();
      controller.text = formatted;
    });
  }
}
```

Then:

```
FocusNode yourNode = FocusNode();
@override
void initState(){
  yourNode.addListener(){
    datePickerListener(yourNode, yourController);
  };
}

 TextFormField(
                focusNode: yourNode,
                controller: yourController,
              )
```

Something like that. Just adjust to your needs.